# Creating Android Emulator for Nougat giving Errors

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-7.0-nougat, android-emulator-plugin

Hello to Emulator Users:

I want to create one Emulator for **Android Nougat** but when I select option for Nougat, Its giving me following errors.

[image]

Comment: According to that errormessage you don't have the images downloaded. Did you check that?

Answer (score 0):

Open SDK Manager and install the highlighted packages
[image]
It should work like charm then.

Answer (score 0):

You can also install the recommended system images from Android Virtual Device Manager.

Create Virtual Device -> Select Phone/Tablet -> Select any Device -> Go to Next Screen. Here you can download the Nougat system images. Better download from Recommended tab.

[Click here to see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GowKu.png)